# $\Delta$-complex structure of $S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-groups, simplicial-complex

I've just started reading about algebraic topology. I've read the definitions of a $\Delta$-complex structure.

I have a couple questions:

How would one construct one for $S^1$? I can see that if we take a 1-simplex and identify its end points, does that work? Also I'm not sure how this can be written explicitly.

Secondly, why are simplicial and $\Delta$ complex structures defined? Is one used in a particular situation where the other isn't?